# Python3 doesn't see Django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

When I attempt to verify that Python3 can see Django by entering `python3` followed by `import django` into the terminal (so I can print Django's version number), I get the following error:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'django'`

Python can detect Django if I enter `python` (followed by `import django`), but not `python3`. How can I correct this so Python3 can also detect Django?

These are the steps I took to install Django on my local machine:

1. Upgraded pip:
   `sudo -H pip3 install --upgrade pip`
2. Downloaded and installed latest version of Python from binary.
3. Created project directory:
   `mkdir django-start && cd $_`
4. Installed virtualenv:
   `pip3 install virtualenv`
5. Created an environment:
   `virtualenv env`
6. Activated the environment:
   `source env/bin/activate`
7. Installed Django:
   `pip install django`

Comment: `pip3 install django`

Comment: Ah, yes! Of course. :) Thank you very much @KirChou!

Comment: If the virtualenv is created for python3, pip install is ok.

Answer (score 4):

You virtualenv is built for Python 2 environment. Cmd `python3` in virtualenv is still using the global Python which doesn't have django.

So if you want to use Python 3 in virtualenv you should add the `-p` or `--python` argument when initialize the env:

```
virtualenv --python $(which python3) env
```

Mind you need remove your old Python 2 `env` folder before you run this command.

Comment: Odd. I went back and entered `pip3 install django` (like in Kir Chou's comment) and now it works. Is there still something else that I'm overlooking, like you point out in your answer?

Comment: If you run `pip3 install` command directly it will install Django globally, since your Python 3 is not in virtualenv the global Django is accessible. And if you just want to install packages globally then you don't need virtualenv.

Comment: I see, so that's definitely something that should be corrected. Thank you!